# vtiger 6 how can i sent emalis plain text or disable the ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, crm, vtiger

Can some one here maybe know how can I sent plain text emails from vtiger 6 **or** maybe some know how can I disable the ckeditor on vtiger 6 ?

10Q

Answer (score -1):

simple and fast way:

1. go to: /layouts/vlayout/modules/Vtiger/resources
2. rename CkEditor.js
   to _CkEditor.js (in case you choose to go back to cke, rename file
   back to original name)